# Ctrl+ Alt+ # no longer working Overleaf LaTeX

Tags: overleaf

I have been using LaTeX for a year or two now and never encounter this problem. In short:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>#</kbd> key use to type a \ now whenever I press the
> <kbd>Alt</kbd>, the cursor changes to a '+' and I can select multiple lines,
> which I don't want to happen.

Anyone have any solutions to this? Even finding a way to disable this feature would be perfect as I can still type \ in every other applications just no longer LaTeX.

EDIT: 65% custom keyboard in American Layout.

Comment: what editor/app are you using?

Comment: Unless you add details about your editor and your system, it seems impossible to answer in a meaningful way.

Comment: apologies, I am using overleaf.com

Comment: you should probably ask overleaf support rather than here. Also you should say something about your keyboard.  For example, a UK keyboard has a `\ ` key so you would not use a ctrl combination to type `\ `

Comment: I have a custom keyboard 65% keyboard in the American layout, that is the reason for the combination. Thank you for the suggestion and Ill be sure to get onto them about it. Reason I asked here was because this place was recommended on one of their support pages.

Comment: I just tried and ctrl-alt-# made `\ ` in both the new and legacy editor on overleaf

Comment: And you have also made me see that my mode was in 'source' instead of 'source(legacy)' and I am now back to typing \. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overleaf is rolling out a new editor based on Code Mirror 6 rather than the old one based on ACE. Mostly the key bindings are the same ( ctrl-alt-# made `\`  in both the new and legacy editor for me) but keybindings are sensitive to lots of things, physical keyboard, operating system, browser, ... may intercept the key combination. The old editor is still available on a `source (legacy)` tab.